How to solve ActiveRecord::ValueTooLong error when using ActionMailbox?
I'm using ActionMailbox in my Rails 7 project to receive inbound emails. I followed the configuration and migration setup as outlined in this guide. The email reception is functioning correctly with Postfix, and the connection is established.
However, from time to time, I encounter the following exception:
ActiveRecord::ValueTooLong in Rails::Conductor::ActionMailbox::ReroutesController#create
Mysql2::Error: Data too long for column 'message_id' at row 1

Upon inspecting my schema, I found that Rails created the following table for ActionMailbox::InboundEmail:
create_table "action_mailbox_inbound_emails", charset: "utf8mb4", collation: "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "status", default: 0, null: false
  t.string "message_id", null: false
  t.string "message_checksum", null: false
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["message_id", "message_checksum"], name: "index_action_mailbox_inbound_emails_uniqueness", unique: true
end

I'm considering a few potential solutions:
Increase field size: Since this is a built-in Rails feature, I'm hesitant to add a new migration to increase the field size.
Custom model: Another option is to create a custom CustomInboundEmail model that inherits from InboundEmail and enforces a limit of 255 characters for the message_id. However, this approach may be risky as it could interfere with existing logic, such as maintaining uniqueness or other constraints.
Do you have any other ideas or suggestions?

Ruby on Rails sets a max length of 255 characters for string columns on MySQL. And while there is no standard that requires a max length for email message ids, there is the recommendation that email header lines should not be longer as 78 characters. Therefore, I would investigate first where the emails with those long ids are coming from, if they look valid and if there is a change to reconfigure the system creating unreasonable long ids.

Thank you. I added logs to see how the message_id looks like. Waiting for exception now and I'll update this post.

I'm all for @spickermann's idea to find out the root cause and don't suggest you just sweep this under the carpet but you don't actually have to worry about changing the column size having any significant side effects. Validations, indices and constraints all work the same no matter what the column length is and the performance implications are most likely negible.

After investigating, the message-id is coming from ListManager server. http://lunar.lyris.com/help/lm_help/11.2/index_Left.html
It looks very strange and very long compare to Gmail.
